# Redrawing image isn't working?

Tags: python, image, pygame, game-physics

So, i have a pygame.circle that i would like to move. I have it moving etc, but it just duplicated the image and doesn't remove the previous. I understand the concept of "Blit" and understand it copies an array of pixels over. So i thought i would try redrawing my whole game, here's what i have:

```
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
                diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)
                diceRollLabel = myFont.render(str(diceRoll), 1, black)
                window.blit(diceRollLabel, (750, 40))
                window.fill(black)
                game()

                count1 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (black),(150, countY - 72 * diceRoll), 25, 0)
                game = False
                game2 = True
                print("Test")

                player1Text = myFont.render(("Player twos turn!"), 1, black)
                window.blit(player1Text, (650, 750))
                pygame.display.update()
                break
```

When it calls "game()" it should recall the function that contains all of the game screen, so the texture etc. but for some reason, it doesn't do anything? The screen just goes black?

it says "Bool object not callable" but my function isn't a boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set game as a Boolean

```
game = False
```

So when you call "game()" it's the same as "False()" which is the reason for your error.

You also fill the screen black after blitting the diceRollLabel (in black), and you then seem to draw a black circle on a black screen.

Full code would be helpful.

Comment: I fixed it to an extent, but now when it calls the function it only displays black

Comment: I don't know what changes you've made but I'd suggest that, if your background is black, then you don't use black for the text, circle. If I make them white then they display on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

Fill the screen at the start of the loop.

```
def draw():
    screen.fill(Color('black'))
    # draw
    pygame.display.flip()
```